# How to connect property tableView to UITableView in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDLcI.png)I am new to iOS programming and I am trying to make a UITableView display a schedule for a hackathon. I can't seem to connect the property I have defined in my .h file to the tableview I have in my ScheduleViewController. When I connected buttons with their associated property I simply held control and dragged the blue line to connect them. I was able to set up dataSource and delegate Outlets by command and dragging them to the circular symbol at the top of my ScheduleViewController. Is there anything else I am missing to set this up?

[ctrl and drag doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDLcI.png)

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #include "Weekend.h"

    @interface ScheduleViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,
        UITableViewDelegate>

    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;


    @end



#import "ScheduleViewController.h"

@interface ScheduleViewController ()

@end

@implementation ScheduleViewController {

    NSArray *allWeekendDays;    
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //Set up schedule for friday
    Weekend *friday = [[Weekend alloc] init];
    friday.day = @"Friday, March 20th";
    friday.events = @"9:00 PM       Check-In\n"
                     "11:00 PM      Opening Ceremony\n"
                     "11:59 PM      Begin Hacks";

    //Set up schedule for saturday
    Weekend *saturday = [[Weekend alloc] init];
    saturday.day = @"Saturday, March 21st";
    saturday.events = @"2:00 AM     Snack Time\n"
                       "8:00 AM     Breakast\n"
                       "1:00 PM     Lunch\n"
                       "7:30 PM     Dinner\n"
                       "10:00 PM    Nerf-Gun Wars\n";

    //Set up schedule for sunday
    Weekend *sunday = [[Weekend alloc] init];
    sunday.day = @"Sunday, March 22nd";
    sunday.events = @"2:00 AM       Snack Time\n"
                     "6:30 AM       Breaskfast\n"
                     "7:30 AM       End Hacks\n"
                     "8:00 AM       Expo 1\n"
                     "9:00 AM       Expo 2\n"
                     "10:00 AM      Closing Ceremony";

    allWeekendDays = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:friday, saturday, sunday, nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    //Defines how many rows will be in my table
    return [allWeekendDays count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //Defines how each individual cell will loook like

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"WeekendCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    Weekend *schedule = [allWeekendDays objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = schedule.day;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = schedule.events;

    return cell;
    //Make a class for weekend days, similar to the president one in the demo
}
@end
```

Comment: can you post an image of your storyboard?

Comment: Let me know if I should zoom in anywhere for you

Comment: you still have to ctrl and drag from your tableview to your respective VC? is that  not working ?

Comment: yeah that's not working. I am uploading another screenshot. I drag the blue line over my tableview and it doesn't highlight like it usually does.

Comment: try changing tableView name to something else, even if that connects it will show an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps, hope it may help

1- Delete the ScheduleViewController both files (Select Remove Reference).

2- ctrl+shift+k (Clean your project)

3- Then go to project directory and again drag SchedularViewController files to project.

4- Now go to storyboard and try reconnecting tableView again.